# How to add or plus times to NOW()

Tags: mysql, vbscript, asp-classic

how to add or plus time to now() with asp database mysql
i am trying with this codes but does not work

```
set prs=server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
    prs.Open "topups",TheDB,adOpenForwardOnly ,adLockOptimistic,adCmdTable 
    prs.AddNew 
    prs("mid")=miid
    prs("epin")=epin
    prs("inr")=mepin("pinprice")
    prs("dattime")=now()
    prs("datt")=now()
    prs("ttime")=now()
    prs("roiadttime")=dateadd(hour,+8,now())
    prs("roibdttime")=dateadd(hour,+16,now())
    prs("roicdttime")=dateadd(hour,+24,now())
    prs("roiddttime")=dateadd(hour,+32,now())
    prs("roiedttime")=dateadd(hour,+40,now())
    prs("roifdttime")=dateadd(hour,+48,now())
    prs("roigdttime")=dateadd(hour,+56,now())
    prs("roihdttime")=dateadd(hour,+64,now())

    prs.Update  
    prs.close
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `hour` with `"h"`, and why to put `+` sign explicitly?

```
set prs=server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
prs.Open "topups",TheDB,adOpenForwardOnly ,adLockOptimistic,adCmdTable 
prs.AddNew 
prs("mid")=miid
prs("epin")=epin
prs("inr")=mepin("pinprice")
prs("dattime")=now()
prs("datt")=now()
prs("ttime")=now()
prs("roiadttime")=dateadd("h",8,now())
prs("roibdttime")=dateadd("h",16,now())
prs("roicdttime")=dateadd("h",24,now())
prs("roiddttime")=dateadd("h",32,now())
prs("roiedttime")=dateadd("h",40,now())
prs("roifdttime")=dateadd("h",48,now())
prs("roigdttime")=dateadd("h",56,now())
prs("roihdttime")=dateadd("h",64,now())

prs.Update  
prs.close
```

Hope it helps, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
call response.write(DateAdd("h",1, Now())
```

Comment: "hh" should be "h". The () for the .write call are wrong.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner: some references the 'hh' thing - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner reponse.write The () ... http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/. Why the -2 ?

Comment: "hh" may be used with the **SQL** function; VBScript's DateAdd needs "h"; see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx wrt the ().

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Personally I prefer to use parenthesis around calls be it `Sub` or `Function` if it's a `Sub` just prefix with `Call` so in this example `Call Response.Write(DateAdd("h", 1, Now())`.

Comment: removed the 'hh' and added the call thanks @Lankymart will never get VBscript anyways