# Date -3 hours in VBscript

Tags: vbscript, date-difference

How can I output a date minus 3 hours? Example:

```
BookDate = 8/4/2014 9:00:00 PM
DesirebleDate = 8/4/2014 6:00:00 PM
```

Tried `DesirebleDate = DateDiff("h", BookDate , -3)` but it is outputing the amount of hours. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add or plus times to NOW()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507437/how-to-add-or-plus-times-to-now)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DesirableDate = DateAdd("h", -3, BookDate)
```

Should set DesirableDate to 3 hours earlier than BookDate.  DateDiff gives the difference between two dates, which is why you are getting the 3...